# node webpack build completing but files return 404 on heroku deploy

Tags: node.js, django, reactjs, heroku, webpack

we're converting the frontend of a django (backend) app to react and using node and webpack to build the dependencies. all the frontend code is in a /frontend folder in the app.

because heroku's node buildpack only looks at app root, I've added a root package.json to guide it to the right build path:

```
{
  "description": "help heroku find path for frontend node app",
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "cd frontend && npm install && npm run build:production"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node":"10.0.0",
    "npm":"6.0.01"
  }
}
```

then inside /frontend is the build:production directive and deps:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js",
    "build:watch": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js --watch",
    "build:production": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-less": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.81.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "styled-components": "^3.2.6",
    "webpack": "^4.8.3",
    "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-plugin-transform-regenerator": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.5.5",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.8.2",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
    "less": "2.7.3",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.0",
    "svg-inline-loader": "^0.8.0",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.5",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^3.1.3",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "^2.22.2"
  }
}
```

when we deploy to heroku, the django app builds fine, and the node app appears to as well (from what I can see):

```
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.0.0
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   6.0.01
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.0.0...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.0.0...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 6.0.01 (replacing 5.6.0)...
remote:        npm 6.0.1 installed
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules (not cached - skipping)
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote:        
remote:        > undefined postinstall /tmp/build_134371d20a788406819fa473e968f043
remote:        > cd frontend && npm install && npm run build:production
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > styled-components@3.3.2 postinstall /tmp/build_134371d20a788406819fa473e968f043/frontend/node_modules/styled-components
remote:        > node ./scripts/postinstall.js || exit 0
remote:        
remote:        Use styled-components at work? Consider supporting our development efforts at opencollective.com/styled-components
remote:        added 1298 packages from 825 contributors in 28.85s
remote:        [!] 5 vulnerabilities found [19545 packages audited]
remote:        Severity: 1 Low | 4 Moderate
remote:        Run `npm audit` for more detail
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > frontend@1.0.0 build:production /tmp/build_134371d20a788406819fa473e968f043/frontend
remote:        > npm run build
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        > frontend@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_134371d20a788406819fa473e968f043/frontend
remote:        > webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js
remote:        
remote:        Failed to load /tmp/build_134371d20a788406819fa473e968f043/.env.
remote:        (node:2622) DeprecationWarning: Tapable.plugin is deprecated. Use new API on `.hooks` instead
remote:        Hash: f6f376fa4847f29e688e
remote:        Version: webpack 4.12.0
remote:        Time: 21391ms
remote:        Built at: 2018-06-21 13:44:03
remote:        Asset      Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
remote:        0ab54153eeeca0ce03978cc463b257f7.woff2  39.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        13db00b7a34fee4d819ab7f9838cc428.eot  96.3 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        c5ebe0b32dc1b5cc449a76c4204d13bb.ttf  96.1 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        a046592bac8f2fd96e994733faf3858c.woff  62.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        e8c322de9658cbeb8a774b6624167c2c.woff2  53.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        8e3c7f5520f5ae906c6cf6d7f3ddcd19.eot   104 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        icons.svg?962a1bf31c081691065fe333d9fa8105   382 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        b87b9ba532ace76ae9f6edfe9f72ded2.ttf   103 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        faff92145777a3cbaf8e7367b4807987.woff  49.3 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        brand-icons.svg?a1a749e89f578a49306ec2b055c073da   496 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        701ae6abd4719e9c2ada3535a497b341.eot  30.4 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        outline-icons.svg?82f60bd0b94a1ed68b1e6e309ce2e8c3   105 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        ad97afd3337e8cda302d10ff5a4026b8.ttf  30.2 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        ef60a4f6c25ef7f39f2d25a748dbecfe.woff  14.4 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        cd6c777f1945164224dee082abaea03a.woff2    12 KiB          [emitted]
remote:        banner.js  3.09 MiB  banner  [emitted]  banner
remote:        search.js  4.07 MiB  search  [emitted]  search
remote:        vendor.js   245 KiB  vendor  [emitted]  vendor
remote:        semantic_theme.css   945 KiB  search  [emitted]  search
remote:        [./node_modules/less-loader/dist/stringifyLoader.js!./semantic_theme/theme.config] 2.17 KiB [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 489 bytes {banner} {search} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/harmony-module.js] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 573 bytes {banner} {search} {vendor} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {banner} {search} [built]
remote:        [./semantic_theme/semantic.less] 41 bytes [built]
remote:        [0] multi styled-components 28 bytes {vendor} [built]
remote:        [1] multi babel-polyfill ./src/search/index.js 40 bytes {search} [built]
remote:        [./src/banner/Banner.js] 11 KiB {banner} [built]
remote:        [./src/banner/index.js] 698 bytes {banner} [built]
remote:        [./src/search/Result.js] 3.06 KiB {search} [built]
remote:        [./src/search/Search.js] 12.3 KiB {search} [built]
remote:        [./src/search/index.js] 599 bytes {search} [built]
remote:        [./src/theme.js] 160 bytes {banner} {search} [built]
remote:        + 1171 hidden modules
remote:        Child extract-text-webpack-plugin node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/dist node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-1!node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!semantic_theme/semantic.less:
remote:        15 assets
remote:        [./node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./semantic_theme/semantic.less] ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-1!./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-2!./semantic_theme/semantic.less 2.77 MiB {0} [built]
remote:        [./node_modules/less-loader/dist/stringifyLoader.js!./semantic_theme/theme.config] 2.17 KiB [built]
remote:        + 76 hidden modules
remote:        up to date in 53.225s
remote:        [+] no known vulnerabilities found [0 packages audited]
remote:        
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules (nothing to cache)
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Pruning devDependencies
remote:        Skipping because NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION is 'false'
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> celery, web, worker
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:        Done: 287.9M
remote: -----> Launching...
```

so I can see that ./src/search/Search.js, ./src/search/index.js built, but when we load the app all those files return 404. they do exist because I can see them in the app:

[image]

but when we load the app on staging server they all err:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “https://test.foo.com/static/js/search.js”.
```

etc.

I'm more used to working with django dependencies and less familiar with node, anyone have any guidance on what's wrong with this build? do we need to find a different way to host and load those static files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was a static file issue - the template tags were not rendering the correct static file path (we followed django-webpack-loader docs as outline here: https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader).

we were rendering the built js with (per docs):

```
{% load render_bundle from webpack_loader %}

...

{% render_bundle 'search' %}
{% render_bundle 'banner' %}
```

once we changed it to:

```
{% static 'js/search.js' %}
{% static 'js/banner.js' %}
```

we can request and load the scripts correctly